# How to insert data Directly inside Iframe of tinyMce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, tinymce, tinymce-4

Suppose this is my data

```
<p>
<span style="color: #99cc00; background-color: #000000; font-size: 18pt;">
Hello testing
</span>
</p>
```

so the data in my tinymce will be well formatted with the background-color and font-size. How can i get this done ?

Comment: Sorry, not clear. You want to store that data into DB using laravel?

Comment: while storing data into database  it gets stored properly along with all the HTML tags but when i fetch the data into my edit page the tinymce Strips off the HTML tags so all the formatting of the contents are lost !!

Comment: You can try `{!! $text !!}`

Comment: i tried that 
Doing this {!! $text !!} . It only displays content without any format like in above example only Hello testing is displayed without any of html properties like color,background-color and font-size !!

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i hope you are understanding whats the actual issue here is . I want the  Format of my content to displayed in proper manner 
like suppose we have <p color="red">You are awsome</p>
so i want "You are awsome" to be displayed in red color in tinyMce

Comment: Ok, wait a moment

Comment: Can you please show me that code?

Comment: In My Blade Template
 
<textarea name="page_content" class="form-control" id="page_content" rows="10" cols="30">
{!!$page->page_content!!}
</textarea>

and for My Tinymce js Initialization
 i have copy pasted code from unisharp filemanager http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/integration

Answer (score 0):

You can tell TinyMCE to validate the elements from html structure by using parameter `valid_elements` and same for validate the styles by using `valid_styles`.

Check this [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements) for more detail.

*Textarea*:

```
<textarea name="page_content" class="form-control my-editor" id="page_content" rows="10" cols="30"> {!!$page->page_content!!} </textarea>
```

*Tinymce script*:

```
var editor_config = {
    selector: "textarea.my-editor",
    valid_elements : 'a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br,span',
    valid_styles: {
        '*': 'border,font-size,background-color,color',
        'div': 'width,height'
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
};

//Load tinymce
tinymce.init(editor_config);
```

Comment: With the same output?

Comment: is there any way by which we can insert data directly into iframe <body> section of tinyMce ...i think if we can do this then it might solve our problem !

Comment: yes, you can do this with `extended_valid_elements`

Comment: BTW, you can check/debug tinyMCE's settings easily within the console of Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools. Just type: `tinyMCE.settings.extended_valid_elements`, to see if your settings are being loaded correctly or not.

Comment: Did you found any luck? you can accept this answer if this is your solution

Comment: Yes . i found the solution . Instead of using textarea i have used div with contenteditable and this has given me the output i was looking for !!